# Juju deploy of kubeflow fails

Tags: ubuntu, kubeflow, juju

I am new to juju and started trying the same in ubuntu 20.04.6 VM by trying instructions in given link to deploy kubeflow

https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/get-started-with-charmed-kubeflow#heading--part-i-access-charmed-kubeflow

Juju controller installation was successful and when I try to deploy kubeflow charm as shown below it just throws TLS handshake failure error

```
$ juju controllers
Use --refresh option with this command to see the latest information.

Controller Model User Access Cloud/Region Models Nodes HA Version
microk8s-localhost* kubeflow admin superuser microk8s/localhost 2 - - 2.9.42

$ juju deploy kubeflow --trust --channel=1.7/stable
ERROR resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": remote error: tls: handshake failure

$ juju deploy kubeflow
ERROR resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": remote error: tls: handshake failure

$ juju version
2.9.42-ubuntu-amd64

$ juju deploy kubeflow --trust --channel=1.7/stable --debug
20:24:25 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running juju [2.9.42 7b871e782195bdac9c90f8a8f01723cc3e08ab92 gc go1.18.10]
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57 args: []string{"/snap/juju/22345/bin/juju", "deploy", "kubeflow", "--trust", "--channel=1.7/stable", "--debug"}
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.jujuclient proxy.go:65 unmarshalled proxy config for "kubernetes-port-forward"
20:24:25 INFO juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.152.183.138:17070]
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:625 starting proxier for connection
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:629 tunnel proxy in use at localhost on port 43975
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://localhost:43975/api"
20:24:25 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:1054 cannot resolve "localhost": lookup localhost: operation was canceled
20:24:25 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://localhost:43975/api"
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.jujuclient proxy.go:65 unmarshalled proxy config for "kubernetes-port-forward"
20:24:25 INFO juju.juju api.go:86 connecting to API addresses: [10.152.183.138:17070]
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:625 starting proxier for connection
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:629 tunnel proxy in use at localhost on port 38075
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.api apiclient.go:1152 successfully dialed "wss://localhost:38075/model/4a2ce290-1cdb-489c-800b-bf0414c8cbef/api"
20:24:25 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:1054 cannot resolve "localhost": lookup localhost: operation was canceled
20:24:25 INFO juju.api apiclient.go:687 connection established to "wss://localhost:38075/model/4a2ce290-1cdb-489c-800b-bf0414c8cbef/api"
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:396 cannot interpret as local charm: file does not exist
20:24:25 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.application.deployer deployer.go:208 cannot interpret as a redeployment of a local charm from the controller
20:24:26 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
20:24:26 DEBUG juju.api monitor.go:35 RPC connection died
ERROR resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": remote error: tls: handshake failure
20:24:26 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:537 error stack:
resolving with preferred channel: Post "https://api.charmhub.io/v2/charms/refresh": remote error: tls: handshake failure
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveCharm:100:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/store.(*CharmAdaptor).ResolveBundleURL:135:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).maybeReadRepositoryBundle:464:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application/deployer.(*factory).GetDeployer:71:
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/application.(*DeployCommand).Run:909:
```